# Verify git commit in bare repo but on a working copy

Tags: git

i have some verification scripts that need to run on a working copy but this task should be done server side in a pre-receive hook to prevent people to push broken things.

the problem is now that the server repo is a bare repo, so i can not run the checks directly in there. I thought about checking out a working copy in the pre-receive script but this unfortunately does not work, because the commit is not available in the repo yet...

How can i do this check?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot verify things that have not been received

Comment: Are you sure you need a working copy?  You can't just pipe the data into your verification script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the pre-receive and the update hook are triggered after transferring the commit, but before updating the refs to the commit.

Both hooks get the sha1 of the transferred commit as an argument. Therefore it should be no problem to check this out into some working copy and do your verification.